# Python Real Time Plotting Memory Leak

Tags: python

I have some simple python code that produces a real-time monitor for looking at data that comes in every second.  It uses matplotlib and works quite well, except that there is a memory leak.  The memory usage of the script slowly creeps up and up over the course of a day, seemingly without bound.  I'm admittedly new to programming python, so was wondering if someone could see something I'm doing that is obviously terrible.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as p
import os
import subprocess as sp
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def main():
    #####Initialize the plot#####
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,axisbg='black') #Set up basic plot attributes
    ax1.set_title('Blip Current vs. Time',color='blue')    
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time (hrs)',color='blue')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Blip Current',color='blue')
    for t in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklines(): t.set_color('yellow') 
    for t in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels(): t.set_color('yellow') 
    for t in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklines(): t.set_color('white') 
    for t in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklabels(): t.set_color('purple') 
    plt.ion() #Set interactive mode
    plt.show(False) #Set to false so that the code doesn't stop here
    i=0 #initialize counter variable (this will help me to limit the number of points displayed on graph

    ###Update the plot continuously###
    while True: #This is a cheap trick to keep updating the plot, i.e. create a real time data monitor
        blip=Popen('adoIf -vo -6 lxf.blip_b3 dataBarM', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0] #Get data to plot
        hr=float(time.strftime('%H'))
        mins=time.strftime('%M')
        secs=time.strftime('%S')
        secadj=float(secs)/3600
        minadj=float(mins)/60
        currenttime=float(hr+minadj+secadj) #Put time into format for easier plotting, i.e. 21.50 for 9:30 pm
        if currenttime >= 0 and currenttime < 0.22: #Set x range properly when rolling over to midnight
            xmin=0
            xmax=currenttime+.01
        else:
            xmin=currenttime-.22 #Limit data to be displayed, only care about recent past
            xmax=currenttime+.01
        try:
            blip =float(blip) #This throws an error if for some reason the data wasn't received at the top of the while statement
        except ValueError:
            blip=0.0
        if i>300: #Limit displayed points to save memory (hopefully...)
            del ax1.lines[0] #After 300 points, start deleting the first point each time
        else:
            i +=1
        if blip > 6: #Plot green points if current is above threshold
            ax1.plot(currenttime,blip,marker='o', linestyle='--',c='g')
        else: #Plot red points if current has fallen off
            ax1.plot(currenttime,blip,marker='o', linestyle='--',c='r')
        plt.axis([xmin,xmax,None,None]) #Set xmin/xmax to limit displayed data to a reasonable window
        plt.draw()
        time.sleep(2) #Update every 2 seconds

if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'Starting Monitor'
    main()
```

Comment: Why are you using a string literal `'true'` instead of the boolean `True`?

Comment: Because I'm a novice.  Thanks, I've changed it.  But I suspect that has nothing to do with my memory issue.

Comment: Are you running on Linux, Windows, Mac ? Subprocess handling is a bit different for each.

Comment: I'm running on redhat linux.

Answer (score 3):

Eureka! I figured it out (well, a workaround at least).  I took the ax1.plot commands out of the while loop, and instead use 'set_xdata' and 'set_ydata' commands along with a fig.canvas.draw() command.  Thanks to everyone for the help, especially reptilicus for pointing out that the ax.plot command creates a new object every time I invoke it.

The x and y values to plot are now stored in arrays, with the first element in each array being deleted on every iteration of the while loop (after a certain number of points are plotted, the number of which is specified in the code using a simple index number i).  Memory usage is flat and cpu usage is less.  Code is as follows:

```
def main():
    #####Initialize the plot attributes#####
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, axisbg='black')#Set up basic plot attributes
    ax1.set_title('Blip Current vs. Time',color='blue')    
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time (hrs)',color='blue')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Blip Current',color='blue')
    for t in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklines(): t.set_color('yellow') 
    for t in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels(): t.set_color('yellow') 
    for t in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklines(): t.set_color('white') 
    for t in ax1.yaxis.get_ticklabels(): t.set_color('purple') 
    plt.ion() #Set interactive mode
    plt.show(False) #Set to false so that the code doesn't stop here
    i=0 #initialize counter variable (this will help me to limit the number of points displayed on graph

    ###Initialize x values####
    times=[] #Create blank array to hold x values
    hr=float(time.strftime('%H')) #Hours
    mins=time.strftime('%M') #Minutes
    secs=time.strftime('%S') #Seconds
    secadj=float(secs)/3600
    minadj=float(mins)/60
    currenttime=float(hr+minadj+secadj) #Put time into format for easier plotting, i.e. 21.50 for 9:30 pm
    times.append(currenttime) #Add first x value to x value array
    if currenttime >= 0 and currenttime < 0.22: #Set x range properly when rolling over to midnight
        xmin=0
        xmax=currenttime+.01
    else:
        xmin=currenttime-.22 #Limit data to be displayed, only care about recent past
        xmax=currenttime+.01

    ###Initialize y values###
    blipcur=[] #Create blank array to hold y values
    blip=Popen('adoIf -vo -6 lxf.blip_b3 dataBarM', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0] #Get first datapoint for plot
    try:
        blip =float(blip) #This throws an error if for some reason the data wasn't received at the top of the while statement
    except ValueError:
        blip=0.0
    blipcur.append(blip) #Add first y value to y value array

    ###Initialize plot###
    line1, = ax1.plot(times, blipcur, 'g-', marker='o')

    ###Update the plot continuously###
    while True: #This is a cheap trick to keep updating the plot, i.e. create a real time data monitor
        hr=float(time.strftime('%H')) #Get new x data for plotting (get current time)
        mins=time.strftime('%M')
        secs=time.strftime('%S')
        secadj=float(secs)/3600
        minadj=float(mins)/60
        currenttime=float(hr+minadj+secadj) #Put time into format for easier plotting, i.e. 21.50 for 9:30 pm
        times.append(currenttime) #Add latest point to x value array
        if currenttime >= 0 and currenttime < 0.22: #Set x range properly when rolling over to midnight
            xmin=0
            xmax=currenttime+.01
        else:
            xmin=currenttime-.22 #Limit data to be displayed, only care about recent past
            xmax=currenttime+.01

        blip=Popen('adoIf -vo -6 lxf.blip_b3 dataBarM', shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0] #Get new y data for plotting
        try:
            blip =float(blip) #This throws an error if for some reason the data wasn't received from previous line of code
        except ValueError: #Just set to zero if there was some temporary error
            blip=0.0
        blipcur.append(blip) #Add latest point to y value array

        if i>285: #Limit data points shown on graph.  Saves memory.
            del blipcur[0] #Delete first element in y value array (oldest/first plotted point)
            del times[0] #Delete first element in x value array
        else:
            i +=1 #Only want to keep making number bigger until I get over the threshold for # points I want, then why bother

        line1.set_xdata(times) #Set x data for plot from x value array
        plt.axis([xmin,xmax,-2,50]) #Set xmin/xmax to limit displayed data to a reasonable window
        line1.set_ydata(blipcur) #Set y data for plot from y value array
        fig.canvas.draw() #Update plot
        time.sleep(2.6) #Update every 2.6 seconds

if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'Starting Monitor'
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that you need to clear the figure each time or matplotlib will keep creating a whole bunch of new objects and things don't get garbage collected. Try something like:

```
fig.clf()
```

as the first thing inside the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will work as the point is to keep a real-time plot displaying with the past ~20 minutes of data visible.  If I add that in then I just get a blank graph.

Comment: I was trying to erase points after I had already plotted 300 points using del ax1.lines[0] which works to get rid of the point (i.e. it disappears from the graph), but somehow data seems to still be piling up.

Comment: Well if you don't clear the figure, then matplotlib creates new objects every time you do an ax.plot(). This will lead to increased mem usage as the process continues.

Comment: What I would do would be to create an empty array outside of the while loop, then push the new data to that as it somes in. Then, just plot that.

Comment: Won't I run into the same problem though?  I will still be executing the plot command over and over again.

Comment: Yeah, but you can just clear the figure and then redraw with the updated array.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code showed you wanted different colored dots depending on the value of `blip`. With your new solution, using `set_data`, you would need a new `Line2D` for each color. An alternative would be to use a scatter plot instead of a line plot. A scatter plot can assign a different color to each dot in the plot.

---

If you want a list of a fixed size, say 285 elements, instead of 
doing this:

```
    if i>285: #Limit data points shown on graph.  Saves memory.
        del blipcur[0] #Delete first element in y value array (oldest/first plotted point)
        del times[0] #Delete first element in x value array
```

you could use [collection.deques](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with `maxlen=285`. With `deques`, you can append to your heart's delight and the `deque` will discard the oldest element when it gets too full. This will make your code a little simpler, since you will not have to manage its size yourself. 
`deques` can also pop the first element off in O(1) time, while `lists` pop the first element off in O(n) time, so there is a [theoretical performance](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) gain here too, though with only around 300 elements it won't make a significant difference.

---

If you have Matplotlib version 1.2 or newer, you can use its `FuncAnimation` class. This will handle much of the boilerplate code for you. Moreover, it allows you to avoid calling `plt.ion()`. (Using `plt.ion()` is not recommended for complicated scripts.)

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections
import datetime as DT
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def currenttime():
    now = DT.datetime.now()
    hr = now.hour
    mins = now.minute / 60
    secs = now.second / 3600
    return float(hr + mins + secs)


def main():
    def animate(data, pathcol):
        xvals, yvals, colors = data
        assert len(xvals)<=300
        if len(xvals) > 1:
            ax.set_xlim(xvals.min(), xvals.max())
        pathcol.set_array(colors)
        pathcol.set_offsets(np.column_stack([xvals, yvals])) 

    def step():
        xvals = collections.deque([], maxlen=N)
        yvals = collections.deque([], maxlen=N)
        colors = collections.deque([], maxlen=N)
        fudge = 0
        while True:
            blip = np.random.random() * 10
            xvals.append(currenttime() + fudge)
            yvals.append(blip)
            colors.append(1 if blip > 6 else 0)
            yield np.asarray(xvals), np.asarray(yvals), np.asarray(colors)
            # make time go faster
            fudge += 0.0001

    # Initialize the plot#####
    N = 300
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(
        1, 1, 1, axisbg='black')  # Set up basic plot attributes
    ax.set_title('Blip Current vs. Time', color='blue')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (hrs)', color='blue')
    ax.set_ylabel('Blip Current', color='blue')

    for t in ax.xaxis.get_ticklines():
        t.set_color('yellow')
    for t in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        t.set_color('yellow')
    for t in ax.yaxis.get_ticklines():
        t.set_color('white')
    for t in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
        t.set_color('purple')
    pathcol = ax.scatter([0,24], [0,10],
                          c=[0,1], s=100,
                          cmap=plt.get_cmap('RdYlGn'), vmin=0, vmax=1)
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
        fig, animate, step, interval=20, fargs=(pathcol,))
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Starting Monitor'
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks!  A lot of good suggestions.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to animation on our work systems.  I wish I did; the example code you gave me is definitely a lot cleaner.  I will incorporate the other changes you suggested, thanks for the tips.  I'm admittedly a little barbaric in my programming approaches (not very experienced) and appreciate when someone shows me a better method for accomplishing something.